# Edited descriptions of multiple events and now they are gone

Tags: google-calendar

Using a Samsung Galaxy A30s and the Google Calendar version 2022.48.2-494681027-release.

I have a weekly recurring event until July 2023 with two more persons.

In order to add more specifics, I edited the description of each (from now until the end), saving "This event" as the next image shows

[image]

Initially, everything was showing up fine and they received emails with the updates.

But now I don't see the text in the description. The same happens in the Calendar of the other two persons.

How to proceed to get back the descriptions in the events? Ideally I wouldn't have to do it all over again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of keeping the recurrent events, I created a separate event for each week with the desired description. In other words, didn't manage to save the time but got the job done.